# How to import meshes from blender 3.++ to javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, blender, javafx-3d

How to import from blender to javafx properly ? I mean with same orientation 'cause blender is z up and javafx is -y up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Importing from blender 3.3.1  to javafx 17.0.2 or ++**

**Blender**

In blender highlight the mesh you want to export , then choose File >> export >> wavefront (.obj).
Since javafx is -Y  axis up and +z forward ; you have to tweak export settings like so :

[image: obj export blender]

**3DViewer**

[3DViewer](https://github.com/Eclion/3DViewer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javafx/experiments/importers/Importer3D.java) app (made with javafx) allow to export into fxml or java class . In this approach I'll export as fxml file

[image: 3dviewer]

**Javafx**

The root of the exported fxml file is `group` node and its child is a `meshview`. In order to cast as meshview we need to erase group and children tags.

This is a single javafx app with a fxml file you can try

**App.class**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-10);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("/suzzane.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        MeshView mesh = (MeshView) loader.getRoot();
        Group group3d = new Group(camera, mesh);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group3d, 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("suzzane import");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**suzzane.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>


    <MeshView id="default">
      <material>
        <PhongMaterial diffuseColor="#93C54B"/>
      </material>
      <mesh>
        <TriangleMesh>
          <points>
            0.467091, -0.308394, -0.768123, 0.411605, -0.129821, -0.794655, 0.633369, -0.242106, -0.566534, -0.411605, -0.129821, -0.794655, -0.466618, -0.309081, -0.76814, -0.633263, -0.24203, -0.566494, 0.348823, 0.039891, -0.626154, 0.546875, -0.054688, -0.578125, -0.348823, 0.039891, -0.626154, -0.546875, -0.054688, -0.578125, 0.243436, -0.183277, -0.809088, -0.243136, -0.183168, -0.809604, 0.065623, -0.241473, -0.664332, 0.15625, -0.054688, -0.648438, 0.296268, -0.364523, -0.805121, -0.293751, -0.363527, -0.805224, -0.066086, -0.241075, -0.663968, -0.15625, -0.4375, -0.648438, -0.351562, -0.515625, -0.617188, 0.546875, -0.4375, -0.578125, 0.351562, -0.515625, -0.617188, -0.248244, -0.648821, -0.854577, -0.253433, -0.768836, -0.748109, -0.730324, -0.381592, -0.681374, -0.261609, -0.481956, -0.761877, -0.006031, -0.325982, -0.829469, 0.109622, 0.127367, -0.784855, 0.404942, 0.022652, -0.679367, 0.207694, -0.152361, -0.750915, -0.102173, -0.130465, -0.742287, 0.017284, 0.984477, -0.591458, -0.065943, 0.865276, -0.683015, -0.272967, 0.886192, -0.649776, 0.081207, 0.860197, -0.701942, 0.356416, 0.923432, -0.574956, 0.065857, 0.759863, -0.734646, 0.14146, 0.23819, -0.733421, 0.130492, 0.225592, -0.812825, -0.130561, 0.226255, -0.812502, -0.091305, 0.118257, -0.792388, -0.138343, 0.24268, -0.73199, 0.031197, 0.157521, -0.82214, 0.0, 0.140625, -0.742188, 0.0, 0.1875, -0.796875, 0.0, 0.195312, -0.75, -0.00351, 0.332462, -0.762465, -0.098573, 0.730395, -0.728907, 0.093144, 0.792467, -0.647164, 0.611977, -0.172832, -0.665211, 0.373829, -0.086535, -0.728236, -0.46076, -0.120128, -0.707842, -0.539893, 0.002377, -0.638478, -0.374026, -0.085633, -0.727129, -0.543159, -0.212734, -0.683209, -0.574115, -0.365077, -0.686721, -0.412973, -0.388532, -0.752534, 0.19815, -0.3041, -0.760369, 0.293952, -0.398592, -0.778324, 0.306832, -0.476701, -0.752781, -0.280962, -0.396572, -0.770937, 0.41156, -0.390627, -0.752042, 0.551672, -0.288132, -0.675783, 0.572695, -0.365439, -0.688196, -0.54685, -0.292564, -0.686891, 0.546875, -0.210938, -0.671875, 0.460938, -0.117188, -0.703125, 0.242188, -0.125, -0.757812, -0.121205, -0.483398, -0.607582, -4.67E-4, -0.418818, -0.744456, 0.05374, -0.428979, -0.616572, -0.261462, -0.709033, -0.606235, -0.457458, -0.528564, -0.474708, 0.795853, -0.151428, -0.417778, 0.717463, -0.403459, -0.312642, 0.841731, -0.416465, -0.572731, 2.82E-4, 0.495311, -0.307091, 0.321192, 0.910612, -0.408725, -0.027229, 0.950352, -0.402103, -0.214052, 0.41023, -0.341908, -0.364485, 0.934935, -0.527463, -0.322199, 0.914282, -0.396656, 0.199753, 0.398234, -0.297475, -0.223717, 0.193371, -0.529801, -0.574942, 0.088264, -0.540223, -0.436074, 0.104066, -0.453043, 0.347695, 0.237654, 0.431147, 0.0, 0.382812, 0.351562, -0.011619, 0.07516, 0.77936, 0.465608, -0.900982, -0.152219, 0.0, -0.984375, 0.078125, 0.0, -0.898438, -0.289062, 0.45972, -0.41102, 0.70957, 0.770823, -0.623203, 0.342437, 0.833846, -0.352238, 0.391235, 0.781498, -0.576058, -0.095848, -0.781498, -0.576058, -0.095848, -0.476077, -0.899132, -0.128827, -0.774117, -0.618565, 0.345925, 0.260303, -0.708855, -0.607407, 0.460237, -0.527298, -0.472638, -0.803836, -0.161472, -0.420019, -0.711654, -0.400774, -0.307327, -0.79584, -0.041023, -0.158112, 0.838238, -0.304138, 0.194035, -0.851212, -0.363598, 0.191879, 0.539567, 0.142898, 0.15848, 0.527753, 0.047276, -0.4504, 0.814251, -0.064879, -0.177529, 0.53391, -0.047078, 0.538381, -0.490828, -0.417757, 0.691108, -0.39169, 0.080613, 0.56466, -1.210536, -0.48592, 0.399701, -1.36325, -0.31343, 0.444733, -1.233435, -0.252704, 0.432477, 1.234498, -0.248681, 0.433467, 1.238196, -0.056204, 0.404615, 1.36328, -0.310916, 0.445376, -0.845118, 0.049599, 0.146843, -1.048997, 0.073373, 0.319236, -0.637334, 0.131573, 0.129306, 1.142695, -0.041631, 0.458032, 1.037881, 0.075968, 0.309556, 1.170774, -0.345162, 0.460286, 1.207696, -0.489413, 0.396355, 0.709322, 0.014957, 0.168345, -0.712712, -0.004226, 0.186871, 0.799217, 0.111136, 0.120197, 0.851778, 4.11E-4, 0.293091, -0.849688, 0.002268, 0.295795, -0.795922, -0.102855, 0.308274, -0.980884, -0.37646, 0.258508, 0.790779, -0.104465, 0.308961, 0.972471, -0.311042, 0.359196, 1.005483, -0.430324, 0.271337, 1.059998, -0.205557, 0.380618, -1.074143, -0.218953, 0.386767, -1.147014, -0.048217, 0.43788, -1.170348, -0.345691, 0.460999, -0.95787, -0.304972, 0.342476, 1.227002, -0.480829, 0.552827, -0.831749, -0.350337, 0.387405, -1.223191, -0.48949, 0.551496, -1.315084, -0.07219, 0.487198, -1.039062, 0.085938, 0.492188, 1.225087, 0.009861, 0.547001, 0.789062, 0.125, 0.328125, -0.15625, -0.054688, -0.648438, 0.15625, -0.4375, -0.648438, -0.546875, -0.4375, -0.578125, 0.223095, 0.182572, -0.53752, 0.582274, 0.083975, -0.538726, 0.701861, -0.406364, -0.701875, -0.852831, -0.421193, -0.58827, 0.253604, -0.768544, -0.74656, 0.252976, -0.656178, -0.850654, -0.196071, -0.294624, -0.761091, -0.22714, -0.134763, -0.760223, -0.352624, 0.254787, 0.24985, 0.0, -0.5625, 0.851562, 0.453125, -0.867188, 0.382812, 0.0, -0.898438, 0.546875, -0.453125, -0.867188, 0.382812, -0.738105, 0.086049, 0.332369
          </points>
          <texCoords>
            0.900073, 0.39930397, 0.865294, 0.40357202, 0.920246, 0.47563398, 0.863045, 0.185498, 0.897948, 0.18823099, 0.914742, 0.11107397, 0.798506, 0.430448, 0.853018, 0.47843802, 0.79513, 0.161614, 0.847458, 0.11125201, 0.860051, 0.36913502, 0.859266, 0.22008902, 0.842259, 0.297248, 0.791018, 0.35455698, 0.897193, 0.36556703, 0.896148, 0.22239, 0.84475, 0.29274702, 0.92118, 0.286287, 0.968213, 0.22978002, 0.968392, 0.426188, 0.968392, 0.354667, 0.434535, 0.619641, 0.424353, 0.599433, 0.354303, 0.679791, 0.438956, 0.65699, 0.52203, 0.65392303, 0.540503, 0.80829203, 0.620264, 0.765208, 0.576273, 0.720769, 0.491024, 0.739273, 0.521557, 0.947385, 0.513037, 0.927336, 0.494152, 0.932383, 0.527362, 0.927079, 0.551123, 0.937522, 0.525584, 0.914574, 0.548649, 0.835652, 0.536374, 0.824051, 0.501713, 0.824062, 0.500449, 0.808166, 0.489319, 0.834218, 0.524426, 0.814906, 0.519841, 0.799157, 0.519132, 0.814618, 0.517577, 0.809393, 0.517872, 0.846092, 0.5083, 0.914279, 0.523492, 0.921718, 0.655324, 0.728105, 0.612627, 0.73852897, 0.408797, 0.730193, 0.391525, 0.749842, 0.42627, 0.736427, 0.39158, 0.71265304, 0.384364, 0.687312, 0.41354, 0.675645, 0.57959, 0.68933904, 0.603696, 0.672222, 0.610356, 0.660578, 0.439501, 0.66901803, 0.626943, 0.67934597, 0.649104, 0.702423, 0.658692, 0.68921, 0.390612, 0.69717896, 0.647785, 0.716514, 0.629829, 0.732737, 0.585166, 0.72900903, 0.492809, 0.565462, 0.523776, 0.613289, 0.537579, 0.566644, 0.415857, 0.569509, 0.350292, 0.603771, 0.722013, 0.738732, 0.766492, 0.69154596, 0.706787, 0.688868, 0.643405, 0.980296, 0.558356, 0.946276, 0.539877, 0.978673, 0.394896, 0.980785, 0.511783, 0.978442, 0.399481, 0.917884, 0.484771, 0.940064, 0.479748, 0.946195, 0.645964, 0.917111, 0.423632, 0.841861, 0.370168, 0.775519, 0.355825, 0.803544, 0.823446, 0.908269, 0.805584, 0.989214, 0.923249, 0.938283, 0.871997, 0.672153, 0.962901, 0.655248, 0.911671, 0.597571, 0.907785, 0.816683, 0.861899, 0.763958, 0.836684, 0.796094, 0.819308, 0.721411, 0.208596, 0.712271, 0.14722, 0.65815496, 0.159892, 0.759454, 0.817923, 0.542867, 0.763149, 0.568545, 0.786595, 0.63099897, 0.279331, 0.54214203, 0.217614, 0.522479, 0.249207, 0.612036, 0.845499, 0.550033, 0.314147, 0.733427, 0.262597, 0.68316, 0.259721, 0.79195297, 0.819338, 0.78603697, 0.203277, 0.782518, 0.78178, 0.858065, 0.68138, 0.79565597, 0.772331, 0.789913, 0.854987, 0.858227, 0.114059, 0.820314, 0.107997, 0.953605, 0.178798, 0.892743, 0.162246, 0.13434899, 0.137396, 0.22570097, 0.185423, 0.21681798, 0.570175, 0.21110398, 0.55487, 0.25643897, 0.618903, 0.21866101, 0.317028, 0.31699502, 0.253991, 0.300781, 0.357746, 0.37724602, 0.52947, 0.248371, 0.504669, 0.295955, 0.553337, 0.18053901, 0.591638, 0.128066, 0.796877, 0.82160103, 0.245969, 0.848998, 0.230248, 0.820848, 0.436457, 0.33172297, 0.393069, 0.30981702, 0.391039, 0.38810903, 0.369361, 0.303954, 0.442893, 0.274863, 0.316181, 0.279792, 0.343481, 0.14339602, 0.332923, 0.25175, 0.305456, 0.13818902, 0.425874, 0.24626398, 0.488922, 0.17751598, 0.451245, 0.12131101, 0.507886, 0.21216601, 0.247626, 0.21315002, 0.22592, 0.255782, 0.202249, 0.18607098, 0.276772, 0.18210399, 0.661965, 0.26444602, 0.707492, 0.240116, 0.742304, 0.40264302, 0.044323, 0.457691, 0.10675, 0.41741103, 0.095807, 0.274346, 0.183755, 0.274588, 0.216123, 0.32187998, 0.568363, 0.287686, 0.658213, 0.414324, 0.484068, 0.371224, 0.498072, 0.447685, 0.791018, 0.23776197, 0.918898, 0.30030298, 0.965038, 0.15832901, 0.611847, 0.840123, 0.667757, 0.776498, 0.680013, 0.679761, 0.330866, 0.682853, 0.619594, 0.603917, 0.609776, 0.62346804, 0.461186, 0.688787, 0.45683, 0.724813, 0.628962, 0.57457304, 0.692106, 0.611726, 0.73401, 0.68208396, 0.232648, 0.996516, 0.24649, 0.90672, 0.994525, 0.832295, 0.91536, 0.740196, 0.999856, 0.74536, 0.011829, 0.844633, 0.1064, 0.567348, 0.043968, 0.632962, 1.44E-4, 0.740887, 0.098965, 0.733032, 0.176788, 0.80382097, 0.196622, 0.844759, 0.392564, 0.17668003, 0.27347, 0.39535397, 0.049526, 0.251176, 0.834578, 0.793121
          </texCoords>
          <faces>
            0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 3, 3, 9, 9, 1, 1, 10, 10, 6, 6, 11, 11, 3, 3, 8, 8, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 12, 12, 15, 15, 11, 11, 16, 16, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 15, 15, 17, 17, 18, 18, 2, 2, 19, 19, 0, 0, 1, 1, 14, 14, 10, 10, 11, 11, 15, 15, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 14, 14, 15, 15, 4, 4, 3, 3, 20, 20, 14, 14, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 19, 19, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 21, 21, 23, 23, 24, 24, 21, 21, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 26, 26, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 34, 35, 35, 36, 36, 35, 35, 34, 34, 26, 26, 37, 37, 36, 36, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 26, 26, 42, 42, 43, 43, 42, 42, 44, 44, 43, 43, 42, 42, 39, 39, 40, 40, 45, 45, 38, 38, 41, 41, 45, 45, 37, 37, 45, 45, 41, 41, 38, 38, 42, 42, 26, 26, 29, 29, 39, 39, 42, 42, 29, 29, 35, 35, 46, 46, 47, 47, 31, 31, 47, 47, 46, 46, 27, 27, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 51, 51, 50, 50, 24, 24, 54, 54, 55, 55, 56, 56, 57, 57, 58, 58, 24, 24, 55, 55, 59, 59, 60, 60, 61, 61, 62, 62, 54, 54, 53, 53, 63, 63, 48, 48, 64, 64, 65, 65, 49, 49, 66, 66, 28, 28, 67, 67, 68, 68, 69, 69, 22, 22, 70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 76, 77, 77, 75, 78, 77, 79, 78, 80, 77, 79, 79, 81, 80, 82, 34, 34, 76, 76, 81, 83, 80, 82, 79, 81, 78, 80, 76, 76, 75, 75, 81, 83, 82, 84, 83, 85, 84, 86, 85, 87, 86, 88, 87, 89, 88, 90, 89, 91, 90, 92, 91, 93, 92, 94, 93, 95, 88, 90, 94, 96, 92, 94, 95, 97, 96, 98, 97, 99, 69, 100, 98, 101, 99, 102, 70, 103, 67, 104, 71, 105, 69, 100, 99, 102, 67, 106, 100, 107, 101, 108, 102, 109, 103, 110, 92, 94, 94, 96, 97, 99, 104, 111, 95, 97, 92, 94, 103, 110, 93, 95, 85, 87, 105, 112, 81, 83, 106, 113, 105, 112, 107, 114, 84, 86, 78, 80, 82, 84, 108, 115, 91, 93, 93, 95, 109, 116, 87, 117, 110, 118, 111, 119, 112, 120, 113, 121, 114, 122, 115, 123, 116, 124, 117, 125, 118, 126, 119, 127, 115, 123, 120, 128, 121, 129, 122, 130, 114, 122, 123, 131, 105, 112, 124, 132, 107, 114, 119, 133, 102, 109, 125, 134, 126, 135, 124, 136, 105, 137, 119, 127, 125, 138, 117, 125, 107, 114, 124, 132, 103, 110, 126, 135, 127, 139, 124, 136, 128, 140, 117, 125, 125, 138, 104, 141, 129, 142, 125, 138, 104, 141, 130, 143, 129, 142, 102, 109, 104, 111, 125, 134, 131, 144, 132, 145, 133, 146, 127, 139, 134, 147, 131, 144, 131, 144, 134, 147, 132, 145, 120, 128, 134, 147, 127, 139, 135, 148, 136, 149, 128, 140, 134, 147, 120, 128, 114, 122, 122, 130, 134, 147, 114, 122, 135, 148, 137, 150, 113, 121, 132, 145, 134, 147, 122, 130, 137, 150, 135, 148, 138, 151, 116, 124, 139, 152, 123, 153, 123, 153, 139, 152, 133, 154, 104, 155, 140, 156, 141, 157, 142, 158, 141, 157, 143, 159, 139, 152, 116, 124, 144, 160, 142, 158, 112, 120, 141, 157, 93, 161, 145, 162, 108, 163, 2, 2, 1, 1, 7, 7, 9, 9, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 10, 10, 13, 13, 146, 164, 11, 11, 8, 8, 16, 16, 11, 11, 146, 164, 14, 14, 147, 165, 12, 12, 14, 14, 20, 20, 147, 165, 18, 18, 148, 166, 4, 4, 18, 18, 4, 4, 15, 15, 82, 84, 79, 81, 32, 32, 82, 84, 32, 32, 40, 40, 5, 5, 4, 4, 148, 166, 32, 32, 79, 81, 30, 30, 149, 167, 36, 36, 34, 34, 27, 27, 26, 26, 149, 167, 27, 27, 149, 167, 150, 168, 82, 84, 39, 39, 51, 51, 82, 84, 51, 51, 83, 85, 48, 48, 72, 72, 74, 74, 48, 48, 74, 74, 151, 169, 150, 168, 48, 48, 27, 27, 150, 168, 72, 72, 48, 48, 51, 51, 100, 107, 83, 85, 51, 51, 23, 23, 152, 170, 51, 51, 152, 170, 100, 107, 151, 169, 74, 74, 153, 171, 151, 169, 153, 171, 154, 172, 154, 172, 153, 171, 68, 68, 154, 172, 68, 68, 25, 25, 22, 22, 152, 170, 23, 23, 21, 21, 25, 25, 68, 68, 21, 21, 68, 68, 22, 22, 25, 25, 56, 56, 58, 58, 25, 25, 58, 58, 154, 172, 58, 58, 62, 62, 151, 169, 58, 58, 151, 169, 154, 172, 54, 54, 23, 23, 51, 51, 54, 54, 51, 51, 53, 53, 23, 23, 54, 54, 24, 24, 48, 48, 151, 169, 62, 62, 29, 29, 28, 28, 56, 56, 29, 29, 56, 56, 25, 25, 39, 39, 29, 29, 51, 51, 25, 25, 24, 24, 155, 173, 30, 30, 34, 34, 33, 33, 30, 30, 33, 33, 31, 31, 29, 29, 25, 25, 155, 173, 40, 40, 32, 32, 46, 46, 40, 40, 46, 46, 45, 45, 31, 31, 46, 46, 32, 32, 46, 46, 35, 35, 36, 36, 46, 46, 36, 36, 45, 45, 29, 29, 156, 174, 52, 52, 29, 29, 52, 52, 51, 51, 43, 43, 41, 41, 42, 42, 36, 36, 37, 37, 45, 45, 39, 39, 41, 41, 43, 43, 37, 37, 26, 26, 41, 41, 38, 38, 41, 41, 39, 39, 149, 167, 26, 26, 36, 36, 40, 40, 39, 39, 82, 84, 33, 33, 47, 47, 31, 31, 33, 33, 35, 35, 47, 47, 156, 174, 29, 29, 155, 173, 28, 28, 27, 27, 49, 49, 64, 64, 48, 48, 62, 62, 64, 64, 62, 62, 61, 61, 58, 58, 60, 60, 62, 62, 155, 173, 24, 24, 59, 59, 58, 58, 57, 57, 60, 60, 55, 55, 54, 54, 63, 63, 98, 175, 69, 69, 68, 68, 98, 175, 68, 68, 153, 171, 48, 48, 65, 65, 49, 49, 68, 68, 67, 67, 70, 70, 68, 68, 70, 70, 22, 22, 99, 176, 153, 171, 74, 74, 99, 176, 74, 74, 73, 177, 153, 171, 99, 176, 98, 175, 71, 71, 101, 108, 152, 170, 71, 71, 152, 170, 22, 22, 77, 79, 76, 76, 34, 34, 77, 79, 34, 34, 30, 30, 100, 107, 152, 170, 101, 108, 72, 72, 150, 168, 106, 113, 84, 86, 83, 85, 100, 107, 77, 79, 30, 30, 79, 81, 86, 178, 157, 179, 110, 118, 86, 178, 110, 118, 87, 117, 78, 80, 77, 79, 80, 82, 149, 167, 34, 34, 81, 83, 78, 80, 79, 81, 82, 84, 149, 167, 106, 113, 150, 168, 108, 115, 85, 87, 87, 89, 81, 83, 75, 75, 86, 88, 81, 83, 86, 88, 85, 87, 86, 178, 75, 78, 78, 80, 86, 178, 78, 80, 157, 179, 87, 89, 158, 180, 91, 93, 87, 89, 91, 93, 108, 115, 72, 72, 106, 113, 107, 114, 102, 109, 84, 86, 100, 107, 159, 181, 160, 182, 89, 91, 159, 181, 89, 91, 88, 90, 109, 116, 158, 183, 87, 117, 96, 98, 90, 184, 89, 185, 89, 185, 160, 186, 161, 187, 89, 185, 161, 187, 96, 98, 91, 93, 158, 180, 160, 182, 91, 93, 160, 182, 159, 181, 160, 186, 158, 183, 109, 116, 160, 186, 109, 116, 161, 187, 73, 73, 94, 96, 88, 90, 73, 73, 88, 90, 99, 102, 109, 116, 140, 188, 97, 99, 91, 93, 159, 181, 92, 94, 97, 99, 161, 187, 109, 116, 159, 181, 88, 90, 92, 94, 97, 99, 96, 98, 161, 187, 96, 98, 95, 97, 101, 108, 96, 98, 101, 108, 71, 105, 90, 92, 67, 106, 99, 102, 90, 92, 99, 102, 88, 90, 90, 184, 96, 98, 71, 105, 90, 184, 71, 105, 67, 104, 94, 96, 73, 73, 107, 114, 94, 96, 107, 114, 103, 110, 72, 72, 107, 114, 73, 73, 102, 109, 101, 108, 95, 97, 102, 109, 95, 97, 104, 111, 119, 133, 157, 179, 84, 86, 119, 133, 84, 86, 102, 109, 97, 99, 140, 188, 104, 111, 157, 179, 78, 80, 84, 86, 81, 83, 105, 112, 106, 113, 81, 83, 106, 113, 149, 167, 109, 116, 110, 118, 162, 189, 109, 116, 162, 189, 140, 188, 162, 189, 110, 118, 157, 179, 162, 189, 157, 179, 119, 133, 142, 158, 136, 149, 113, 121, 142, 158, 113, 121, 112, 120, 85, 87, 108, 115, 105, 112, 111, 119, 130, 143, 104, 141, 123, 131, 114, 122, 116, 124, 127, 139, 126, 135, 121, 129, 127, 139, 121, 129, 120, 128, 136, 149, 142, 158, 118, 126, 123, 131, 133, 146, 132, 145, 123, 131, 132, 145, 122, 130, 117, 125, 136, 149, 118, 126, 114, 122, 120, 128, 115, 123, 137, 150, 111, 119, 113, 121, 111, 119, 137, 150, 138, 151, 111, 119, 138, 151, 130, 143, 138, 151, 135, 148, 128, 140, 138, 151, 128, 140, 129, 142, 131, 144, 124, 136, 127, 139, 128, 140, 125, 138, 129, 142, 103, 190, 124, 136, 131, 144, 103, 190, 131, 144, 133, 146, 129, 142, 130, 143, 138, 151, 136, 149, 117, 125, 128, 140, 145, 162, 144, 160, 121, 129, 145, 162, 121, 129, 126, 135, 135, 148, 113, 121, 136, 149, 118, 126, 143, 159, 162, 191, 118, 126, 162, 191, 119, 127, 93, 161, 139, 152, 144, 160, 93, 161, 144, 160, 145, 162, 115, 123, 121, 129, 144, 160, 143, 159, 118, 126, 142, 158, 115, 123, 144, 160, 116, 124, 112, 120, 111, 192, 141, 157, 111, 192, 104, 155, 141, 157, 133, 154, 139, 152, 93, 161, 140, 156, 162, 191, 143, 159, 140, 156, 143, 159, 141, 157, 145, 162, 126, 135, 105, 137, 145, 162, 105, 137, 108, 163, 103, 110, 133, 193, 93, 95
          </faces>
          <faceSmoothingGroups>
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8388608, 8388608, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4194304, 0, 0, 0, 536870912, 4194304, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2097152, 2097152, 1048576, 1048576, 0, 0, 0, 524288, 524288, 262144, 262144, 131072, 131072, 0, 0, 0, 65536, 65536, 32768, 32768, 16384, 16384, 0, 8192, 8192, 4096, 4096, 2048, 2048, 1024, 1024, 0, 0, 512, 512, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 128, 128, 0, 64, 64, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, -2147483648, -2147483648, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1073741824, 1073741824, 0, 0, 536870912, 0, 0, 268435456, 268435456, 134217728, 134217728, 67108864, 67108864, 0, 0, 33554432, 33554432, 0, 0, 16777216, 16777216, 8388608, 8388608, 4194304, 4194304, 2097152, 2097152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1048576, 1048576, 524288, 524288, 262144, 262144, 131072, 131072, 0, 65536, 65536, 32768, 32768, 0, 0, 16384, 16384, 8192, 8192, 4096, 4096, 2048, 2048, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 1024, 0, 512, 512, 0, 0, 0, 256, 256, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 64, 0, 32, 32, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0
          </faceSmoothingGroups>
        </TriangleMesh>
      </mesh>
    </MeshView>
```

**result**

*this is a decimated version of suzzane primitive

[image: import 3d javafx]